# Method of Reflection for Wave Equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to seek a representation formula for the solution of

\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0 , & |x|<1,t>0,\\
u(-1,t)=u(1,t)=0, &t>0,\\
u(x,0)=g(x), u_t(x,0)=h(x),  & |x|<1.
\end{cases}

using d'Alembert's formula and the method of reflection (also known as the method of images). The hint says to consider intervals of the form $(2k-1,2k+1)$ and $(2k+1,2k+3)$ where $k$ is an integer and find a suitable extension of $g,h$ to these intervals.

Next it asks to apply the initial condition $u(x,0)=\max(0,1-2|x|)$,  $u_t(x,0)=0$ and solve and plot the solutions for $t=0,1/2,3/4,1,5/4,3/2,7/4,2$ to show the reflection effect of the end points $x=+1,-1$.

The method of reflection was discussed briefly in the [book](http://wwwhome.math.utwente.nl/~antoniosa/teach/pde11/half_line_dirichlet.pdf) for the one dimensional wave equation on the half line, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this circumstance and what graphically these waves should look like.